# JMeter: Connection Timed out error in JMeter script

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

I am trying to create a JMeter script for an application hosted in public cloud. But when I try to record or replay, the connection to site fails with following error. But the same site/application works via browser with no issues.

I have already tried launching the JMeter using the PROXY host & port (since I am behind a enterprise proxy/firewall), but it did not work. Any suggestions/workarounds help. Thanks in advance.

Error: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] failed:       Connection timed out: connect

Answer (score 0):

Your error message means that the connection attempt to the website fails due to timeout, but we cannot comment what exactly needs to be done unless we see more detailed stacktrace.

You could try:

1. Enabling [Java debug logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) for HTTPS connections by adding the next line to *system.properties* file:

   ```
   javax.net.debug=all
   ```
2. Enable [JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for HTTP components by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
   ```
3. If the proxy is really "enterprise" you might need to set your domain via [`http.proxyDomain`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#proxy_config) JMeter property